# Unittest verify async method Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, concurrency, completable-future

I want to verify that when run methodA, my code run through methodB asynchronously (1 time) like below

```
public class ClassA {

    @Inject
    @Named("executor")
    ExecutionContextExecutor eventHandlerExecutor;

    public Object methodA (Object x, Object y) {
        ...
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> methodB(i, j), eventHandlerExecutor);
        ...
    }

    public void methodB (Object n, Object m) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How should I write a unit test for this?

```
classA.methodA(x, y);

// can spying classA help to verify it?
verify(classA, times(1)).methodB(any(), any());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can spy the `ClassA` instance you want to test. The nice thing of a spy is that it allows you to test the real thing but at the same time can also let you to verify if certain of its method are really executed or not.

Another nice thing is that it allow you to add some codes that will be executed before actually executing the real method by using `doAnswer()`. So you can make use of it to capture the thread name that is used to execute methodB for verification later , and also setup a `CountDownLatch` such that the main thread will wait for the aysnc. thread to finish before proceeding.

So something likes as below after combining all of these :

```java
@Test
void test(){
    ClassA sut = new ClassA(xxx);
    sut = spy(sut);

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    AtomicReference<Thread> asyncThreadRef = new AtomicReference();

     doAnswer(ans -> {
            try {
               asyncThreadRef.set(Thread.currentThread());
                return ans.callRealMethod();
            } finally {
                latch.countDown();
            }
     }).when(sut).methodB(eq(aaa), eq(bbb));
    
    sut.methodA(aaa,bbb);
    latch.await(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    verify(sut, times(1)).methodB(aaa, bbb);
    assertThat(asyncThreadRef.get()).isNotSameAs(Thread.currentThread());   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this info, I know what spy can do, but the main point is I want to verify the method in async, how to combine spy to achieve that

Comment: understood. just update my answer for that

Comment: Thank you, your update has all the details that I needed, 5 stars

Comment: Since you are constructing a new `String` via `StringBuilder`, it will never be the same (object) as the already existing thread name (string object). You have to use `isNotEqualTo` to check the string content. But why do you compare thread names instead of the actual thread reference at all? Use `AtomicReference<Thread>` instead  of `StringBuilder` and do `reference.set(Thread.currentThread())` inside the operation and `assertThat(reference.get()).isNotSameAs(Thread.currentThread());` in the final test.

Comment: @Holger, thanks for the code review . i very much agree what you said . Your suggestion is very useful. let me update the codes